# Open Command line + inputs for GUI

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, netbeans, terminal

I am trying to write a java GUI in netbeans for executing a program on the command line, and currently have this piece of code assigned to a button

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try
        {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");


            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null)
            {
            System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
            } 
     catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

This opens the terminal, however I would like to know how I should go about inputting commands into the terminal while still just pressing the button (ex: "ls", "cd", "javac" etc) Thanks!

UPDATE:
@Codebender My code now looks like this.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
            new PrintStream(pr.getOutputStream).println("ls");
```

I am getting the error "cannot find symbol, symbol: variable getOutputStream, location: variable pr of type process" and a red line under getOutputStream. Any ideas?

@Codebender So should it be like this?

```
new PrintStream(pr.getOutputStream{println("ls")});
```

Comment: @Codebender I have not. Could you show me in code how this would look? I tried just copying and pasting this line of code into my script, but I don't believe that is how it should be executed. I'm fairly new to this aspect of java. Thanks :)

Comment: @Codebender I added a comment after the end of my post in response.

Comment: So it should be like this? (See Update in post)

Comment: I have updated it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use outputStream to write to the terminal. Wrap it up with a printstream to make things easier.

```
Process pr = rt.exec("open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(pr.getOutputStream());
ps.println("ls" + System.lineSeparator());
// Follow with the reading of output from terminal.
```

If your `Terminal.app` is the default linux terminal, instead of opening a new one you can try,

```
Process pr = rt.exec("ls");
// Follow with the reading of output.
```

Comment: This didn't do anything :(. It just pulled up my terminal then finished like before "exited with error code 0" (finished the program essentially). Is there anyway I can give more information? I feel like I am probably doing something wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Shambaree Check if my alternate solution works for you.

Comment: Nope. :( All I want to do is enter a command into the terminal and execute it after it is being opened. I'm in Netbeans on OSX by the way